# Find the number of x-digit numbers whose product of digits is N

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

Given two numbers \$N\$ and \$x\$, find the number of \$x\$-digit numbers whose product of digits is \$N\$

\$N <10^6\$ and \$x <12\$

```
Sample Input (N x):
8 3
Sample Output:
10
```

Comment: shortest codelength or shortest runtime? Seems for this one, shortest runtime with codelength?<1000 (say) would be a more meaningful target.

Comment: I don't understand: 2 digits x and N, x=8, N=3 means 8 digits where the product is 3. Since 3 is prime, it can only be 3111...1, 1311...1, 113... - 8 possibilities. What am I missing?

Comment: @userunknown It's the other way round: three digits where the product is eight. (222, 811, 181, 118, and six ways to arrange 1,2,4, I believe.)

Comment: @breadbox: I meanwhile recognized that, but the description should be fixed. If I'm giving two numbers N and x, it shouldn't be claimed that I'm given two numbers x and N (which is the ordering in the headline too).

Answer (score 3):

#### Golfscript <s>42</s> 31

```
~10\?.10/\,>{10base{*}*1$=},,\;
```

**Input:** Expects the numbers `N` and `x` as command line arguments (separated by space).

The program can be tested [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc4IDMnCgp%2BMTBcPy4xMC9cLD57MTBiYXNleyp9KjEkPX0sLFw7).

Comment: I tested and got a `Code took longer than 5 seconds to run, so it was aborted.` with the parameters reversed. :)

Comment: @userunknown You are right. The code is very inefficient when `x` goes above 4. For example, if I run it on my machine with the parameters `3 5` I get the result after 30+ seconds. So for `3 8` I guess it could be hours...

Comment: I never looked into this Golfscript-thingy. Is it almost always that slow?

Comment: @userunknown Golfscript's purpose is not speed and it's known to be a little slow. However, in this case it's the algorithm that's very inefficient. But the code is short :)

Comment: @userunknown I will test this algorithm in C# as well to see how it compares.

Comment: @userunknown the C# version runs for parameters `3, 8` in about 30s on my machine. See my C# answer below. Or above. :) So yes, GolfScript is kinda slow.

Comment: @userunknown, GolfScript is interpreted in Ruby. Also, all values are immutable, so there's a lot of copying involved. It doesn't tend to be fast, and can often add a power or two of n to the asymptotic runtime of algorithms which are usually analysed in the RAM model.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Scala is of course not interpreted, but run as compiled Bytecode. But the values are almost always immutable too - this needn't be too slow. My solution uses 0 mutable vars, just immutable vals but generates f(524288, 7) or f(256, 12) in less than the 5s the online machine for Golfscript does. I was curious whether this is an endless loop.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `>`. I think you can shorten `:z;,{z>},` to `\,>`

Comment: Also `\`1/{~}%` could probably be `10base`

Comment: In fact I think this can come down to 31 using `?` for powers and eliminating some unnecessary complication in the second filter.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks! I was way under par with that program. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) 2, 13 bytes

```
{h.&t~lℕẹ≜×}ᶜ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#ASAA3///e2guJnR@bOKEleG6ueKJnMOXfeG2nP//WzgsM13/Wg)

### Explanation

```
{h.&t~lℕẹ≜×}ᶜ
{          }ᶜ   Count the number of
         ≜      values at this point
   &t           formed via taking the last element of the input,
       ℕ        generating an integer
     ~l         of that length,
        ẹ       and splitting it into digits
          ×     such that the product of those digits
 h.             is the first element of {the input}
```

One neat golfing trick used here is that unlike almost all metapredicates, `ᶜ` doesn't care at all about the actual value of `.` (which is normally used to construct an output for the metapredicates); as such, `.` can be used like any other variable (saving a byte because it appears implicitly before `}`). There are no implicit labelisations anywhere here, so I had to add an explicit labelisation using `≜` to give `ᶜ` something to count.

Answer (score 1):

### Scala 107:

```
def f(N:Int,x:Int,s:Int=1):Int=if(s==N&&x==0)1 else
if(s>N||x==0)0 else
((1 to 9).map(i=>f(N,x-1,s*i))).sum
```

ungolfed, debugfriendly version:

```
def findProduct (N: Int, sofar: Int, togo:Int, collected:String=""):Int={
  if (sofar == N && togo == 0) {
    println (collected)
    1
  } else
  if (sofar > N || togo == 0) 0 else 
  (1 to 9).map (x=> findProduct (N, sofar*x, togo-1, collected + " " + x)).sum
}
```

Invocation with debugging output:

```
scala> findProduct (3, 1, 8)
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3
 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1
 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1
 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1
 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1
 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1
 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1
 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
res175: Int = 8

scala> findProduct (8, 1, 3)
 1 1 8
 1 2 4
 1 4 2
 1 8 1
 2 1 4
 2 2 2
 2 4 1
 4 1 2
 4 2 1
 8 1 1
res176: Int = 10
```

Comment: I've tested it on simplyscala.com and it's really fast. +1 for performance.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
⁵Ḷṗ⁸P€ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//4oG14bi24bmX4oG4UOKCrMSL////M/84)

Fun fact, this (as far as I can tell) would've worked, atom-for-atom, when [ais523's answer was posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116191/66833).

### How it works

```
⁵Ḷṗ⁸P€ċ - Main link. Takes N on the left and x on the right
⁵       - 10
 Ḷ      - Ḷowered range; [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   ⁸    - N
  ṗ     - Cartesian power; Yield all N-length sublists of [0, 1, ..., 9]
     €  - Over each:
    P   -   Take the product
      ċ - Count occurrences of x
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 164 bytes

```
from itertools import *
N,x=map(int,raw_input().split())
print len([c for c in product([d for d in range(1,10)if N%d==0],repeat=x) if reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,c)==N])
```

Answer (score 0):

#### C# 128

```
int Z(int n,int x){var i=(int)Math.Pow(10,x-1);return Enumerable.Range(i,i*9).Count(j=>(j+"").Aggregate(1,(a,c)=>a*(c-48))==n);}
```

This C# method returns the number of `x`-digit numbers whose product of digits is `n`. It requires that namespaces `System` and `System.Linq` are imported in the current context.

Online version: http://ideone.com/0krup

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell 117 chars

```
import Data.Char
main = print $ f 3 8
f n t = length[x|x<-[10^(n-1)..(10^n-1)],foldr(*)1(map digitToInt $ show x)==t]
```

Answer (score 0):

## K, 49

```
{+/x=*/'"I"$''${x@&~x in y}.!:'"i"$10 xexp y,y-1}
```

.

```
k){+/x=*/'"I"$''${x@&~x in y}.!:'"i"$10 xexp y,y-1}[8;3]
10
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 40 bytes

```
[:+/[=[:*/"1(10#~])#:(10^<:@])}.[:i.10^]
```

Generates all `x`-digit numbers, convert each to base 10, then find the product of each number, and test whether each number is equal to the left hand side, and then find the sum of each boolean.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
,’⁵*r/ḊDP€ċƓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARwA4///LOKAmeKBtSpyL@G4ikRQ4oKsxIvGk///OP8z)

Takes \$x\$ as a command line argument and \$N\$ on standard input.

### Explanation

```
,’⁵*r/ḊDP€ċƓ
,             On {the input} and
 ’            {the input} minus 1
  ⁵*          take 10 to the power of each of those numbers
    r/        then form a range between them
      Ḋ       without its first element;
       D      treat each element as a list of digits,
        P€    take the product of each of those digit lists,
          ċ   then count the number of times
           Ɠ  the value from standard input appears
```

The hard part is generating the list of numbers with *x* digits; the lowest such number is \$10^{x-1}\$, the highest is \$10^x-1\$ The range here is generated via first generating the pair \$(x,x-1)\$, then taking 10 to the power of both of those, and then generating the range between them. The range includes both endpoints by default; just in case *N* happens to be 0, we need to remove the top end of the range (which comes first because it's a "backwards" range) using `Ḋ`.